# android - Boot Receiver not firing

Tags: android, xamarin.android, permissions, alarmmanager, android-alarms

So I have an app which is based on recurring tasks using AlarmManager and I want the Alarm to be initialized if the device was restarted

Therefore, I made a Boot Receiver, code ahead:

```
    [BroadcastReceiver(Enabled = true)]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionBootCompleted })]
    public class BootReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
    {
        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            Log.Write("BootCompleted Alarm was received.");
            Alarms.Init(context);
        }
    }
```

I have also gained the permission using:

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Manifest.Permission.ReceiveBootCompleted)]
```

When checking on my device Settings for the app's permission, it has the permission.

So, why doesn't it fire?

Comment: Does my solution work for you? If yes, can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:).

Comment: It it not working on all devices or on some devices? did you try it on emulator? for example on Nexus S

Answer (score 0):

Some restriction in new api which is causes a problem when you register to receive broadcasts based on system events (eg. AlarmManager)

In the document [Statically registering a Broadcast Receiver with an Intent Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/broadcast-receivers#statically-registering-a-broadcast-receiver-with-an-intent-filter):

> In Android 8.0 (API 26 and above), [Google placed limitations](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html) on what
> apps can do while users aren't directly interacting with them. These
> limitations affect background services and implicit broadcast
> receivers such as Android.Content.Intent.ActionBootCompleted. Because
> of these limitations, you might have difficulties registering a Boot
> Completed broadcast receiver on newer versions of Android. If this is
> the case, note that these restrictions do not apply to foreground
> services, which can be called from your broadcast receiver.

[Implicit Broadcast Exceptions](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions.html)